# Netbeans denies presence of Library even though it's there

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to use the MSSQL JDBC driver to create a simple mapper.

For some reason though, it says that the `jdbc` package doesn't exist in `com.microsoft.sqlserver` but as you can see further up in the picture I can import the entire driver just fine.

I've had this issue before but I forgot how to solve it.

How do I fix this?

[image]

**EDIT** Just don't be an idiot like me, and remember to include a `string` instead of a class next time.

Comment: Can you import the library?

Comment: I was an idiot, it has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class.forname takes a string as parameter.
wrap your com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver with ".

code should look like this :

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Comment: Some times I am confused as to why I was allowed to code in the first place. Cheers! It works now.